# Bitwise Operator | and + the same?

Tags: java

Looking at `|`, it is described as  a bitwise operator `OR`.
So, in this code example:

```
private int getColorRGB(int color) { // 255255255 would be white, 000255000 green, etc.

    if (color < 0) return -1;

    int r = color / 1000000 % 1000;
    int g = color / 1000 % 1000;
    int b = color % 1000;

    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255) throw new IllegalArgumentException("RGB values cannot exceed 255.");

    return (r >> 16) | (g >> 8) | b; // POINT OF INTEREST
}
```

I can replace the 2 `|` at the line marked with `POINT OF INTEREST` with `+`, and I still get the same output.

The method takes an int `rrrgggbbb`, so 255 would be blue, `200200200` would be light gray, etc.

So, my question is; what is the difference between the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 2; // binary 0x10
b = 2; // binary 0x10

c = a + b; // c = 4
c = a | b; // c = 2
```

`|` is a bit operation and it doesn't equals `+`

Sometimes it gives the same result: `2+1` and `2|1` for example; but it isn't a rule

Comment: "Sometimes", i.e. exactly iff `a & b == 0`?

Comment: @tobias_k, we are talking about OR, not about AND - isn't it?

Comment: @tobias_k that makes sense to me: 
a=0b1010 ,
b=0b0101 ,
a&b: 0b0 ,
a|b: 0b1111
a+b:0b1111

Comment: Yes, we are talking about OR, but `x|y` is not just "sometimes" the same as `x+y`, but exactly if `x&y==0`, i.e. `(x|y == x+y) == (x&y == 0)`

Comment: @tobias_k, now I see what you mean; yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

`|` takes the bitwise OR means takes the greater corresponding bit of the two numbers while `+` takes the addition of the two corresponding bits and takes further carries which means `1+1` gives us as `10` while `1|1` will stops only to `1`. `|` will never cause out of range if larger argument is in range while `+` can have out or range if if sum of both causes a number out of range.
If in two numbers, corresponding bits are different, then only in that case `|` acts as `+` because during summation, carries never produces.

Answer (score 2):

Remember | and + are 2 different operators. That being said, sometimes they can have the same result, like 1*1 and 1/1. While they have the same result, they do not go through the same process.